# not able to get data by quereing the BigQuery dataset via API

Tags: google-bigquery

I have just started exploring the BigQuery platform.I have successfully implemented the streaming input and listing the data from the tables via API.

Now I am trying to query the tables via API, but getting below error even having the role "Owner" on the project and the dataset.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access Denied: Table eminent-expanse-134408:_f0217d6d035af97e7c4a87ad93962ba4c594717d.anonabb84babe0de5db5b0a1151dfa1857fcea3e92cd: The user abhinandan@eminent-expanse-134408.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have permission to read data from a table in dataset eminent-expanse-134408:_f0217d6d035af97e7c4a87ad93962ba4c594717d",
    "reason" : "accessDenied"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Denied: Table eminent-expanse-134408:_f0217d6d035af97e7c4a87ad93962ba4c594717d.anonabb84babe0de5db5b0a1151dfa1857fcea3e92cd: The user abhinandan@eminent-expanse-134408.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have permission to read data from a table in dataset eminent-expanse-134408:_f0217d6d035af97e7c4a87ad93962ba4c594717d"
}
```

What I am  missing? Shall I am suppose to enable billing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a service account (`abhinandan@eminent-expanse-134408.iam.gserviceaccount.com`), not your user account. The service account would need to be either a member of the project or a (at least a ) reader on the dataset ACL in order for you to be able to read the data.

Comment: I have verified the the service account's authority.It's owner for the project. Still I am getting the same error.